# Rollover buttons in a div

Tags: css

Ok, I'm fairly new to CSS and am following this Rollover Buttons code (http://www.elated.com/articles/css-rollover-buttons/). The thing is I want 9 buttons (3x3). If I repeat the code and rename the id's, they all repeat in line down the page. I'm thinking I want to make div's, but not sure where to go next.

HTML:

```
<a id="emailUs" href="#" title="Email Us"><span>Email Us</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
#emailUs
{
    display: block;
    width: 107px;
    height: 23px;
    background: url("emailUs.gif") no-repeat 0 0;
}

#emailUs:hover
{ 
    background-position: 0 -23px;
}

#emailUs span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
}
```

How would I now repeat this code so that I have 9 buttons in a 3x3 grid?

Comment: `display: block;` is what makes them form a list instead of a grid.

Comment: Thank You. Still so many little things to learn. Most of these comments really help to better understand the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to go about this, the simplest would probably be to make three divs each being a row of three links. You can see it [here on codepen](http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/blCpF)

Comment: Thank You. This works for me. I'm just a couple months into coding so asking questions, copying, pasting, and tinkering with code is what I need. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem! I tried to make it as simple as possible. If you could please mark it correct that would be wonderful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all 9 a tags something like this`<div id="wrapper"> 9*<a href="..."> </div>.` Beacause your a tags are having fixed width (107px) you can force your wrapper to have fixed width of 240px, but you still have to remove display: block;

Try hacking this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bk44c/

Other solution for your grid: add a `float: left; margin: 5px` to your a tags and increase the width of your wrapper `width: 400px;`

Regards